# Canceling current long gesture to drag a view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have `controllerA`, I add some  `UIView` subclass to it .
This view has a `long press gesture` inside it, so when you long press it, it delegate to `controllerA` about it.

Now, **while** user is long pressing that view, I want to start dragging it (in controllerA) by panGesture that I'v added to controllerA .

The only problem is, that the *current long press* on that view( inside its class), is eliminating the pan gesture from `controllerA`.( I can drag it only when I remove my finger)

Doing :

```
view.userInteractionEnable=false
```

**after** the long press started- will not cancel touches and let me drag, and I can't find a way to cancel the current gesture unless I remove my finger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a much simpler strategy .
If you want to start dragging an element while long press, you do not need to use pan gesture .

You can simply set long press and set `allowableMovement` to something big, then you translate the movement to your view's axis :

```
   let long:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.long))
        long.allowableMovement=3000
        view.addGestureRecognizer(long)
```

Then you translate the coordinates with :

```
      let point = obj.location(in: view.superview)
   if(action == "began"){draggedPoint = point} //save starting point
    if(action == "changed")
    {
        view.frame.origin.x+=point.x-draggedPoint.x //translate to our view and drag
        view.frame.origin.y+=point.y-draggedPoint.y
        isDragging=true
    }
```

So because the movement is the distance from the view's left corner on start, you simply save this point when we **begin** pressing, and then measure the distance, and simply move your view .

Works great .

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, use this function and return needed state for your recognizers:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so I'v tried to add this to both classes but it didn't work. I think that the problem is that the upper view will not get touches that being taken from him by the subview (long press)